# Error in loading files from a csv while training an LSTM

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I am relatively new to tensorflow and am trying to train a two layer LSTM in tensorflow for some data I crawled, and saved into a CSV. But, after I use the methods shows on the tensorflow website, I keep getting the following error:

> TypeError: inputs must be a sequence

The original code is:

```
file = tf.train.string_input_producer(['players_raw.csv'],
num_epochs=100, shuffle=False)
reader = tf.TextLineReader()
key, val = reader.read(file)
gameNum, age, team, homeAway, opponent, pointDiff, secs, orb, drb, ast, stl, blk, to, pts, fanPts = tf.decode_csv(val, record_defaults=defaults)
features = tf.pack([gameNum, age, team, homeAway, opponent, pointDiff, secs, orb, drb, ast, stl, blk, to, pts])
label = tf.pack([fanPts]);

lstmCell = rnn_cell.LSTMCell(NUM_FEATURES)
stacked = rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstmCell] * 2)
outputs, states = rnn.rnn(stacked, features, dtype=tf.float32)
```

The last line is what causes the error. I think I understand what the problem is, but I am not sure how I would go about fixing it

Comment: *I think I understand what the problem is*, what do you think?

Comment: Have you tried to turn the inputs into a sequence with Python's awesome typing? `list("[1,2,3,4,5]")`. You may also want to find the help or documentation on the RNN module you are using. I couldn't find anything on any RNN module within Python. And I'm 99.9% sure that it's the RNN not the CSV that are the problem.

Comment: It's hard to answer without knowing what 'players_raw.csv' looks like. And is there a longer stack trace that error is coming from. Seeing would help as well. And what does the `rnn` definition look like, or at least what does it's return line look like for `rnn`?